# BSSID of Nearby Networks w/ Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, mac-address, bssid

How can I retrieve the BSSID / mac address and strength of nearby WiFi networks (not the local device) from an Android / iOS application? This application has been built using Titanium. Titanium.Platform provides the macaddress for the device, not the outside networks.

If this is not possible using the current API, does anyone know of / have a module that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the BSSID with the TI platform. You can write a module that can read it. It will be something like:

```
NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
id info = nil;
for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
    info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
    BSSID=[info valueForKey:@"BSSID"];
    if (info && [info count]) {
        break;
    }
    [info release];
}
[ifs release];
return BSSID;
```

However, do note that there is a bug as of IOS 5 that prevents you from reading the BSSID if the SSID is the same on all your APs. It won't refresh the BSSID properly. I'm still waiting on a fix or alternate solution so if anyone has something I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mac address information using [Titanium.Platform](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Platform-module).